# Spring container instantiates, configures, and assembles a object

Tags: java, spring

[Spring docs:](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-factory-scopes-prototype)

> the container instantiates, configures, and **otherwise assembles a
>   prototype object**, and hands it to the client, with no further record
>   of that prototype instance.

we know that the container instantiates, configures, and assembles a object, and hands it to the client. but I can't understand why did it say **otherwise**?

Container always assembles a object. **it doesn't assembles a object if instantiating and configuring fail. it will do that always.**

I cant understand why did it say "otherwise".

does "otherwise" have any different meaning in this sentence?

Comment: "Assembling" can include things like applying `@Transactional` AOP advice to it.

Comment: @chrylis-onstrike- I thought assembling means Integrating the object with their dependencies. and why otherwise? what is contrast between instantiating-configuring and assembling?

Comment: Instantiate: `new`. Configure: `set`. Assemble: wrap with a `TransactionInterceptor`.

Comment: *"instantiates, configures, and assembles"* makes it sound like "instantiate", "configure", and "assemble" are 3 different non-overlapping actions, but the word "assemble" includes both "instantiate" and "configure", so the word "otherwise" simply means "in addition to the actions already mentioned", e.g. other actions like injection, proxying, and finalizing (@PostConstruct).

Comment: >"In contrast to the other scopes," ... (otherwise;)

Comment: You start to cite after a colon.... It is better to understand when considering the above/previous: The whole statement goes: "In contrast to the other scopes, Spring does not manage the complete lifecycle of a prototype bean: the container instantiates, configures, and otherwise assembles a prototype object, and hands it to the client, with no further record of that prototype instance."

Comment: ...and that's why otherwise, because in no other scope "a prototype object" is assembled. (but all of the other stuff;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*"instantiates, configures, and assembles"* makes it sound like "instantiate", "configure", and "assemble" are 3 different non-overlapping actions, but the word "assemble" includes both "instantiate" and "configure".

The word "otherwise" simply means "in addition to the actions already mentioned", e.g. other actions like:

- Injection (e.g. `@Autowired`)
- Proxying (e.g. `@Transactional`)
- Finalizing (e.g. `@PostConstruct`)
- ...